# javax.persistence.Query with Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement a namedQuery (javax.persistence.Query) with Generics. This is working for single objects:

```
public <T extends Status> T fStatusByCode(Class<T> type, String code)
{
    Query nq = getManager().createNamedQuery("f"+type.newInstance().getClass().getSimpleName());
    nq.setParameter("code", code);
    T result=(T)nq.getSingleResult();
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately this can not directly applied to get all objects:

```
   public List<T extends UtilsStatus> allStatus(Class<T> type)
    {
        ...
        List<T> lResult = (List<T>)q.getResultList();
        return lResult;
    }
```

The *extends* in the method **public List....** seems to be terrible wrong, but I don't get the picture. How is the syntax to get a `List<T>`?

Thank you, Thor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the generic type before you use it in `List`:

`public <T extends UtilsStatus> List<T> allStatus(Class<T> type)`

Answer (score 3):

Use JPA 2 and it's [`EntityManager.createNamedQuery(jpql, Class)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method.
It returns a [`TypedQuery`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) which is what you should use.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, now I'm using a CriteriaQuery